# @valid @requestBody kotlin with entity into entity

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a problem with valid request in kotlin because I currently have an object composed of a list of integers and another entity called emailData, when I send incomplete or in error format emaildata, the validation does not happen and let me enter the controller. my code this and my request in postman these

```
 fun sendMessage(@Valid @RequestBody notificationData: NotificationData) {
    this.notificationManager.sendNotificationByType(notificationData)
}

data class NotificationData(
    @get:NotEmpty
    @get:NotNull
    @field:NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
    @get:JsonProperty("notification_type")
    var notificationType : List<Int> = listOf(),

    @Valid
    //@ @field:NotEmpty(message = "SRTERST enter id")
    @get:JsonProperty("email_data")
    var emailData : EmailData = EmailData()) 

data class EmailData(

    @NotNull
    @get:NotEmpty
    @get:JsonProperty("email_receiver")
    var emailReceiver : List<String> = listOf(),


    @NotNull
    @get:NotEmpty
    @get:JsonProperty("subject")
    var subject : String = "",

    @get:NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @get:JsonProperty("template_id")
    var templateId : String = "",


    @get:NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @get:JsonProperty("template_params")
    var templateParams : HashMap<String, String> = HashMap())
```

when i send

```
{
"notification_type":["0"],
"email_data":{

    "subject":"test",
    "template_id":"d-1860fd6fa461449b88c578b124a0b331"

}
```

}

the validation for the emailData no work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? :)